# get candles from orderbook

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, quantitative-finance

I would like to create OHLC candles based on orderbooks. I have a pandas Series with date as index and mid price as values.

```
2020-08-04 18:06:40.207934746+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:40.453107131+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:41.009450726+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:41.206957872+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:41.534236063+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:42.207130934+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:42.764421770+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:43.202200290+00:00    3.9415
2020-08-04 18:06:43.451386494+00:00    3.9440
2020-08-04 18:06:43.962340203+00:00    3.9440
```

I tried to do something with pd.Grouper like that:

```
mid_price.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=interval)).agg({
                                    "open":  "first",
                                    "high":  "max",
                                    "low":  "min",
                                    "close":  "last"
                                })
```

But I have an error: nested renamer is not supported

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new df, since the number of rows and columns (and the columns themselves) will be different. Pandas provides a function for candlesticks, you can create one with this snippet

```
ohlc_df = df['price'].resample('1D').ohlc()
```

creating a new df with the fields open high low close.

*edit: I think I actually remember running into the same error, if I can remember correctly it's being thrown in agg, and it had something to do with creating new columns while doing a groupby or resample*

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFrame resample function, and pass time_frame of candles and base time for close candles

```
def candle_timeframe_converter(orders: pd.DataFrame, time_frame: str, base: str):
try:
    candles_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    candles_dataframe['High'] = orders['price'].resample(time_frame, base=base).max()
    candles_dataframe['Low'] = orders['price'].resample(time_frame, base=base).min()
    candles_dataframe['Open'] = orders['price'].resample(time_frame, base=base).first()
    candles_dataframe['Close'] = orders['price'].resample(time_frame, base=base).last()
    candles_dataframe['Timestamp'] = orders['timestamp'].resample(time_frame, base=base).first()
    return candles_dataframe.dropna()
except Exception as e:
    return e
```

note that name of DataFrame columns depends on your data and in the end you can drop any non-numeric data if you need to.